# Mysql keeps crashing on El capitan OSX

Tags: mysql, macos

so i am having some troubles with my mysql, a week ago i upgraded to PHP7 and my mysql stopped working due to PID problem, i then uninstalled mysql entirely, installed it from a DMG (mysql/oracle site) and now it is working intermittently.

I do `mysql.server start` then i can enter to `mysql -u root` but when i do `exit;` i cannot run the `mysql -u root` again, its the same on phpmyadmin, i go in, start editing a table and puff, mysql not running. When i try to reaccess i get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Then i have to `mysql.server stop` and `mysql.server start`.

Ready to post any other info that you need, please help me!

**EDIT:**

Specs: Macbook pro mid 2015 (16GB i7)

Error log

```
2016-03-22T03:49:31.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
2016-03-22T03:49:50.359928Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-03-22T03:49:50.359944Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-03-22T03:49:50.359956Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2016-03-22T03:49:50.359960Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-03-22T03:49:50.359988Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360459Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360466Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360497Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360502Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360513Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360517Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360520Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360522Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360525Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360527Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360529Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360532Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360534Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360536Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360539Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360541Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360543Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360546Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360548Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360550Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360559Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360562Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360564Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360566Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360569Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360571Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360574Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360576Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360578Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360581Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360583Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360585Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360588Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360590Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360593Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360626Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-03-22T03:49:50.360670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-03-22T03:49:50.463584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-03-22T03:49:50.463985Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 160322  0:49:50
2016-03-22T03:49:51.416436Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3497954
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417401Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417410Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417414Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417417Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417420Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'keyring_file'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.417632Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-03-22T03:49:51.418402Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2016-03-22T03:49:51.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Adans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
2016-03-22T03:49:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-03-22T03:49:54.633056Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-03-22T03:49:54.633214Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.633219Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.633276Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.633318Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 56748 ...
2016-03-22T03:49:54.637249Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-03-22T03:49:54.639661Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-22T03:49:54.639674Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-03-22T03:49:54.639680Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-03-22T03:49:54.639683Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-03-22T03:49:54.639915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-03-22T03:49:54.640013Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-22T03:49:54.650176Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-03-22T03:49:54.659805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-22T03:49:54.674908Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.683688Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-03-22T03:49:54.683860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-03-22T03:49:54.702986Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.703633Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.703641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.703844Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-03-22T03:49:54.754428Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.11 started; log sequence number 3497954
2016-03-22T03:49:54.754585Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-03-22T03:49:54.754691Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.757605Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 160322  0:49:54
2016-03-22T03:49:54.758053Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.758064Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.758814Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.758855Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.758920Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 13222
2016-03-22T03:49:54.759447Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.759466Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-03-22T03:49:54.759480Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-03-22T03:49:54.773637Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-03-22T03:49:54.773738Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that MySQL is just "crashing."  In a true crash, MySQL will actually try to restart itself and often will succeed.  There's usually a reason for instability, external to MySQL itself -- like insufficient memory or bad hardware.  Find the MySQL error log, and read it.  `SELECT @@LOG_ERROR;` while the server is running is the easiest way to find the path to the error log.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Edited the post, please check

Comment: The only thing really unexpected here is the first line.  The rest looks like you stopped the server normally then started it again about 3 minutes later, and it started without incident.  The next time the issue occurs, capture everything beginning with the line at 2016-03-22T03:49:54.773738Z (the last line of a normal startup) and let's see what it looks like.